# QProgressBar Error

Tags: qt4

I am trying to add QProgressBar in my code but having some troubles. I added progress bar via Designer and in the code, I pass the pointer to QprogressBar object to a separate thread to have it update QProgressBar as it's processing data, however, I get this message:
../../src/xcb_lock.c:77: _XGetXCBBuffer: Assertion `((int) ((xcb_req) - (dpy->request)) >= 0)' failed.
I am running Qt-4.5.0 on Ubuntu 8.10(2.6.27-11).
I also tried Qt-4.3.5 in RHEL5(2.6.18) and I get different error, something cryptic like X error with QPaint error.
It's seems to be fine when I updates progress bar from my main app exec loop.

Please help
Nimesh

Answer (score 3):

The `QWidget` class and all of its subclasses, including `QProgressBar`, are not reentrant and can not be used outside of the main thread.  Refer to the following documentation:

http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/threads.html#threads-and-qobjects

You are getting errors because you are trying to update the `QProgressBar` from outside of the main thread.

The preferred way of updating the progress bar is to make an object affiliated with your data processing thread emit a signal periodically as it progresses, then connect this signal to the `setValue(int)` slot in `QProgressBar`.  Qt will ensure that the signal-slot connection is thread-safe.  Refer to the documentation on connecting signals and slots across threads:

http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/threads.html#signals-and-slots-across-threads

Hope this helps.