# How do I create a Window in different QT threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, user-interface

I have an application in which each thread (except the main thread) needs to create its own window. I tried creating a thread and then calling `this->exec()` in the `run` function. However, I get an error before I even get to that call: `ASSERT failure in QWidget: "Widgets must be created in the GUI thread."`

I want to popup a message window. The problem is that the source has multiple threads each of which may need to popup its own message.

Comment: Don't attempt to show UI from the background/worker threads. Instead show that UI from the main GUI thread. Arrange for your background/worker to signal the GUI thread in order to get this done. This example shows how to do it: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/thread-basics.html#example-3-clock.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you need to create QWidget(or some other gui component(s)) in different(non-main) thread(s) you can implement it in such way:

- Create simple wrapper which holds gui component:

  ```
  // gui component holder which will be moved to main thread
  class gui_launcher : public QObject
  {
    QWidget *w;
    // other components
    //..
  public:
    virtual bool event( QEvent *ev )
    {   
      if( ev->type() == QEvent::User )
      {
        w = new QWidget;
        w->show();
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
  };
  ```
- create QApplication object in main thread
- another thread body:

  ```
  ..
    // create holder
    gui_launcher gl;
    // move it to main thread
    gl.moveToThread( QApplication::instance()->thread() );
    // send it event which will be posted from main thread
    QCoreApplication::postEvent( &gl, new QEvent( QEvent::User ) );
  ..
  ```
- be happy, :)

Comment: Hello I made some small improvement just for fun    
 template<typename mygui>
    class gui_launcher : public QObject
    {
      mygui *w;
      // other components

    public:
   void add2Gui()
    {
    this->moveToThread( QApplication::instance()->thread() );
    QCoreApplication::postEvent( this, new QEvent( QEvent::User ) );
    }

      virtual bool event( QEvent *ev )
      {   
        if( ev->type() == QEvent::User )
        {
          w = new mygui;
          w->show();
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      }
    };

Answer (score 7):

Qt will only let you create GUI elements in the GUI thread - what is it that you need to display from the other threads? See something like [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2806730/101645) for an example of updating a progress bar with data from a non-GUI thread.

**Update:**

If you want to show a message for each window, you can have a class like this:

```
class MyWorkerThread : public QThread
{
  Q_OBJECT
signals:
  void sendMessage(QString msg);
private:
  void run()
  {
    /* do stuff */
    emit sendMessage(QString("This thread is doing stuff!"));
    /* do more stuff */
  }
};
```

Then connect it up to your GUI via the signal-slot mechanism with something like:

```
connect(workerThread, SIGNAL(sendMessage(QString)),
        guiController, SLOT(showMessageBox(QString)));
```

Where the `showMessageBox` function does what you need it to do.

Comment: sry for the wait, i was testing your answer out.

Comment: Here is a full example of calling a QMessageBox from a QThread.  It is very similar to your example. https://stackoverflow.com/a/23992291/999943

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible.  Other non-GUI components can run in other threads and will usually communicate via the signal/slot mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

The above answers can be combined with a `QAction` object (or custom class objects) to transfer any action to the main GUI thread to be executed, not just creating widgets or displaying a message box. (e.g. by emitting `sendAction(QAction*)`, or implementing a custom `QEvent` class embodying a `QAction*`.)