# How to call GUI elements in different Qt threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, user-interface

I have an application in which a thread (not main thread) needs access to the GUI's elements (send a click action, show a message box, etc). I am working in python and Qt and also know that it is not possible when in not main thread.
Is there a way to do it?  I mean to send the action that I want to do in the thread to the main thread.

Comment: i would like to do something like this but in python:[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777911/how-do-i-create-a-window-in-different-qt-threads]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a good tutorial on how to use Qthread: http://joplaete.wordpress.com/2010/07/21/threading-with-pyqt4/ . This will show how to call the GUI elements in different and custom threads. Hope this helps.