# How do i call GUI elements in different Qt threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, user-interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to call GUI elements in different Qt threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13664267/how-to-call-gui-elements-in-different-qt-threads)

I have an application in which a thread (not main thread) needs to access to GUI's elements (send a click action, show a message box, etc).Am working in python and Qt and i also know that it is not possible in not main thread.
Is there a way to do it, i mean to send the action that i want to do in the thread to the main thread?
i have tried :
de

```
f myfunc(q):

            self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('trie'))
            try: line = q.get_nowait()
         # or q.get(timeout=.1)
            except Empty: 
                pass #No hacer nada  si la linea de texto es null
            else: # got line
    # ... do something with line

                self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('trie')) 


        thread = threading.Thread(target=myfunc, args=(q,))
        thread.start()
```

And to connect:

```
self.connect(self.thread, QtCore.SIGNAL('tri'), self.prueba)
```

But it is not working, i think that the sender is not recognized like :`self.thread`
Here is my error:

```
Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GApp'" in <bound method VBoxManager.__del__ of <GNS3.VBoxManager.VBoxManager object at 0xa13e14c>
```