# QDialog::exec() blocks the application

Tags: c++, qt

I currently have a formA that requests input from a user using another form that inherits from QDialog. The form is prompted using QDialog::exec. Now the problem is that there are going to be multiple instances of formA thus whenever any of formA opens up another form as a dialog the entire application blocks.Currently I have something like this

```
if(formUserInputRequired->exec()==1) //Block until the user selects from a form
{
}
```

Is there a way to make QDialog::exec not block the entire application I just want it to block only the instance of the form it was called on or something like that but definitely not the entire application?

Update:
I do not need a blocking window. However I would like for a way to know when the user is done with the input in another form so that the original form can process that data

Comment: @sara not possible all QWidgets must be in the main thread

Comment: @ratchetfreak it is possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777911/how-do-i-create-a-window-in-different-qt-threads however not trivial, so I deleted my comment

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Call the `setWindowModality` method on the dialog with `Qt::WindowModal` as the argument.

```
Qt::NonModal          0  The window is not modal and does not block input to other windows.
Qt::WindowModal       1  The window is modal to a single window hierarchy and blocks input to its parent window, all grandparent windows, and all siblings of its parent and grandparent windows.
Qt::ApplicationModal  2  The window is modal to the application and blocks input to all windows.
```

[Source](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qt.html#WindowModality-enum)

Answer (score 2):

You can use show() instead, and then to grab dialog result you connect the signal of accept to a slot of your formA to treat it, just like:

```
connect(formUserInputRequired, SIGNAL(accept()), this, SLOT(acceptClicked());
formUserInputRequired->show();
```

Comment: One closing bracket is missing in the `connect`

Answer (score 1):

set the [modality](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#windowModality-prop) of the dialog to `Qt::WindowModal` (the default of QDialog is `Qt::ApplicationModal`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `show()` method instead of `exec()`, because `exec` method has it's own event loop.