# Create QT plugin with FireBreath on Windows

Tags: qt, plugins, firebreath

First of all,sorry for my english.

I wrote a FireBreath plugin with QT and the plugin can show normally.

But when I click a button in the plugin window,nothing happened.And all widgets like this.

But that button changed when I resize the browser.

Am i forgot some event-handling or window-updating operations in QT?

Thanks for any advice!

The `QApplication` created in `onPluginReady()`function.

```
void MediaPlayerPlugin::onPluginReady()
{
    static int argc=0;
    static char **argv={ 0 };
    new QApplication(argc, argv);
}
```

And the `QWidget` is a child of the plugin window(note:the `m_player` is a `QWidget` subclass).

```
bool MediaPlayerPlugin::onWindowAttached(FB::AttachedEvent *evt, FB::PluginWindow *pluginWindow)
{
    FB::PluginWindowWin* wnd = reinterpret_cast<FB::PluginWindowWin*>(pluginWindow);
    HWND hwnd = wnd->getHWND();

    m_player = new MediaPlayer();

    HWND childHwnd = (HWND)m_player->winId();

    LONG oldLong = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE);

    ::SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, oldLong | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS);
    ::SetWindowLong(childHwnd, GWL_STYLE, WS_CHILD | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS);
    ::SetParent(childHwnd, hwnd);


    FB::Rect pos = wnd->getWindowPosition();
    m_player->setGeometry(pos.left,pos.top,pos.right-pos.left,pos.bottom-pos.top);
    m_player->show();
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be that QApplication is going to essentially take over the process it is running in, which is a problem when you are running as a plugin.  You don't own the process -- you don't get to decide any of the interesting details.

Short answer is that if there is a way to do this, I've not found it.  One instance where I needed to do something similar I ended up launching the QApplication executable as a separate process and communicated with it via STDIN/STDOUT.

Comment: Thanks,I've solved my problem.I just create another thread in the`onPluginReady()`function,and create `QApplication` in the thread.And this helped me -- [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777911/how-do-i-create-a-window-in-different-qt-threads)